# How to reverse a Flash animation?

Tags: animation, adobe-flash

I have an animated globe that is spinning from the right to left. Since this is supposed to simulate [Earth's rotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_rotation), it should be from the left to the right.

How can I reverse the already created animation on the timeline?

**Note:**
For this particular case, we are talking about a simple animation where two layers get moved from point A to point B and loop takes care of the rest.

<sup>If relevant I am using Adobe Flash Professional CS6.</sup>

Comment: Ask Superman to fly backwards around your animation really really fast.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum He said no, he's filming with Batman right now... any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing a screen shot of your setup, or how your animation is laid out, it may be as easy as:

1. Highlight your frames in the timeline
2. Right-click > **Reverse Frames**

That's if your globe is a stop-animation where each key frame represents a position. If not, then you'll need to provide more detail on your setup so we can be more helpful.

[image: Reverse Frames]

Answer (score 0):

Pity, it does not consider "Shape hints" while reversing (shape tweens).

*Update:*
But what seems to work for that case is:

1. Convert the Animation to Frame-by-Frame Animation
2. THEN reverse.